# Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb results in Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I have a .Net Framework 4.7.1 web application project.

When I add the NuGet package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, my project fails to start, giving me the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It happens right after I add the above-mentioned package. Without it everything works perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

I have Visual Studio 2017 15.5.5. Maybe it's some version conflict problem? I also have Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core and Microsogt.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework packages installed.

Comment: What kind of project are you using?

Comment: It's a regular web application project. There're 2 other class libraries in the solution. Targeted framework - 4.7.1.

Comment: What I'll like to know if it is using the asp.net project with global.asax or the startup class one?
If I remember correctly the point of Owin.Host.SystemWeb is to run Owin projects on top of IIS, do you have an startup class?

Comment: It has a Global.asax class in it. I tried adding an Owin startup class into the App_Code folder as well, still getting the error. It was marked with "[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(EMG.YubiPromo.WebSite.Startup))]" attribute.

Comment: The startup class should be on the root of the project, at the same level as the global.asax file, try to follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Well, it's a complete different way, I was trying to integrate Owin security into my existing app, and now I have to build a new Owin app from scratch and migrate all my code to it.

Comment: If you install the System.Runtime package, does it start working?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I tried that, it didn't work. I had migrate all code into the new application.

Comment: @AndreyKorneyev thanks. If you're still having an issue, please log an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues with detailed steps to reproduce. Even better if you can upload your app to GitHub and it should be even easier to investigate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though a delayed reply. Still posting if anyone else having same issue.

Add below key in appSettings section in web.config file

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="<<Namespace>>.Startup, <<Assembly>>" />
```

for e.g.

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="<<Namespace>>.Startup, <<Assembly>>" />
```

or, only Startup class with Namespace and without Assembly

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="<<Namespace>>.Startup" />
```

Comment: This did not solve for me, do you have any other ideas possibly ? Quite stuck and can't find much on the issue